# Loading environment specific properties file in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I am working on a spring-boot application, I need your assistance on below scenario.

I have properties files for each environment something like application-dev.properties, application-prod.properties etc. Is there way that my application can load environment specific properties file by using spring @Profile annotation.

Please help.

Comment: Spring boot already does that by default, specify the active profiles at startup and spring boot will load `application.properties` and an `application-{profile}.properties` for you.

Comment: read this thread here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45512798/2685581

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `@Profiles` annotation at all. Just use

```
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:myapp-${environment.type}.properties")
```

and define environment type via system property. E.g. via command line `-Denvironment.type=dev`.

Answer (score 0):

@Profile is not for loading environment specific properties file. It is for specifying profile of a bean. For example,

```
@Profile("dev")
@Component
class Foo {

}
```

It means the bean of `Foo` is only available when the active profiles include `dev`. Or the opposite `@Profile("!dev")`, which means the bean is available when `dev` is not an active profile.

So for loading environment specific properties file, since it is `spring-boot`, you can just specify the active profiles. There are several ways to specify the active profiles.

- Environment variable: `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev,prod`
- command line argument: `java -jar app.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev,prod`
- Programmatically : `SpringApplicationBuilder(...).properties("spring.profiles.active=dev,prod).run(...)`
- Default application.properties or yaml: `spring.profiles.active:dev, prod`