# Using env variable in Spring Boot's application.properties

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, openshift

We are working on a Spring Boot web application, and the database we are using is MySQL;

- the setup we have is we first test it *locally* (means we need to install MySQL on our PC);
- then we push to Bitbucket;
- Jenkins automatically detects the new push to Bitbucket and does a build on it (for Jenkins mvn build to pass we also need to install MySQL on the virtual machines that is running Jenkins).
- if Jenkins build passes  we push the code to our application on OpenShift (using the Openshift deployment plugin on Jenkins).

The problem we have, as you may have already figured it out, is that:

- in `application.properties` we can not hard code the MySQL info. Since our project will be running in 3 different places (*local*, *Jenkins*, and *OpenShift*), we need to make the datasource field dynamic in `application.properties` (we know there are different ways of doing it but we are working on this solution for now).

  ```
    spring.datasource.url = 
    spring.datasource.username = 
    spring.datasource.password =
  ```

The solution we came up with is we create system environment variables locally and in the Jenkins VM (naming them the same way OpenShift names them), and assigning them the right values respectively:

```
export OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST="jdbc:mysql://localhost"
export OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT="3306"
export OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME="root"
export OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD="123asd"
```

We have done this and it works. We have also checked with `Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();` that the environment variables can be made into java variables as such:

```
String password = env.get("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD");   
String userName = env.get("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME");   
String sqlURL = env.get("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST"); 
String sqlPort = env.get("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT");
```

Now the only thing left is we need to use these java variables in our `application.properties`, and that is what we are having trouble with.

In which folder, and how, do we need to assign the `password`, `userName`, `sqlURL`, and `sqlPort` variables for `application.properties` to be able to see them and how do we include them in `application.properties`?

We have tried many things one of them being:

```
spring.datasource.url = ${sqlURL}:${sqlPort}/"nameofDB"
spring.datasource.username = ${userName}
spring.datasource.password = ${password}
```

No luck so far.  We are probably not putting these environment variables in the right class/folder or are using them incorrectly in `application.properties`.

Comment: Read [@ConfigurationProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) to learn more. However, this is a perfect use case for [Profile specific configuration properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties)

Comment: spring.datasource.url=${nmi_spring_datasource_url}
spring.datasource.username=${nmi_spring_datasource_username}
spring.datasource.password=${nmi_spring_datasource_password}

This worked for me. I added the above 3 environment variables into System Variables.

The only weird thing was that I had to close and open my IntelliJ to make Spring boot "read" it.

OP: were you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: @shortduck What version of spring did you use?

Answer (score 503):

You don't need to use java variables. To include system env variables add the following to your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.url = ${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/"nameofDB"
spring.datasource.username = ${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password = ${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD}
```

But the way suggested by *@Stefan Isele* is more preferable, because in this case you have to declare just one env variable: `spring.profiles.active`.  Spring will read the appropriate property file automatically by `application-{profile-name}.properties` template.

Comment: can you please give a link to the reference fragment about using env variables in the application.properties files?

Comment: Found my self http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-placeholders-in-properties

Comment: This method is more convenient for docker linking. For instance: `docker run --name my-tomcat -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 -e APP_DB_DB=mydb -e APP_DB_USER=dbuser -e APP_DB_PASS=dbpass --link mongo-myapp:mongo -v /path-to/tomcat/webapps:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps -d tomcat:8-jre8-alpine`

Comment: This is absolutely the best way to go. Using environment variables means you don't need to list secrets in plain text along side your application. This is significantly more secure and reduces dependency on your source code access security measures to protect your entire estate. An accidental SO post with properties included doesn't result in information leaking out.

Comment: I wanted to add to this and mention that if you are using spring boot(didn't check if it works without boot), then any property can be overriden via an environment variable automatically without modifying your application.properties.   ie, if you have a property called `spring.activemq.broker-url` then the corresponding environment variable would be: `SPRING_ACTIVEMQ_BROKER_URL`.   periods and dashes are automatically converted to underscores.   This is extremely convenient when working with containers/spring boot.

Comment: it is spring.profiles.active, not spring.active.profiles

Comment: If you design for cloud it's not a preferable way to use Spring profiles. Using environment variables is recommended by the 12 factor app standard:
https://12factor.net/config

Comment: @Carmageddon as far as I know, Spring cloud bootstrap phase happens before ApplicationContext is loaded. So Spring simply can't add vars from `bootstrap.properties` to the `Environment`.

Comment: I know this topic is a bit old. But you can combine both environment variable setup and spring profile setup. You dev profile should have static information while your production profile can make use of the environment variables. In this way dev's no longer need to define environment variables on their machine if they just want to deploy the development profile.

Comment: @abe thanks for in the information. I checked the spring doc and it depends on how do you inject environment variables. according to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-vs-value, `@value` doesn't support the flexible binding but `ConfigurationProperties ` can do as what you described.

Comment: This doesn't works for me, for some reason my spring app is trying to reach this route: ${mongo_port}:27017 instead of localhost:27017

Comment: Does the environment variables resolve in windows based environment? The syntax for environment variable seems like linux.

Comment: @Master Chief yes it does

Comment: @underscore_05 Yup, that's how I'm doing it

Comment: @abe I think that only works for Spring own properties and not your custom properties

Comment: There's an unfortunate gotcha with this: If Spring Boot can't find the environment variable specified by the placeholder, it silently leaves the placeholder unexpanded.

Comment: What about when datasource is MongoDB ReplicaSet and I need to pass X-number of members?

Comment: Nice thanks. How can I use the ${DB_PASSWORD} but make it encrypted

Comment: @antak Your comment gave me a hint that led me to finally solve my issue after 2 days of debugging. I checked the logs and found it attempting to log in with the unexpanded variable and going by your comment, I knew they weren't being picked up. Turns out I needed to restart WebLogic and not just redeploy the application in order for my newly set env variables to be made available to applications running in the container.

Comment: How can we place environment variables in a file and have Spring load them into the environment?

Answer (score 119):

The easiest way to have different configurations
for different environments is to use spring profiles.
See [externalised configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

This gives you a lot of flexibility.
I am using it in my projects and it is extremely helpful.
In your case you would have 3 profiles:
'local', 'jenkins', and 'openshift'

You then have 3 profile specific property files:
`application-local.properties`,
`application-jenkins.properties`,
and `application-openshift.properties`

There you can set the properties for the regarding environment.
When you run the app you have to specify the profile to activate like this:
`-Dspring.profiles.active=jenkins`

Edit

According to the spring doc you can set the system environment variable
`SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` to activate profiles and don't need
to pass it as a parameter.

**is there any way to pass active profile option for web app at run time ?**

No.
Spring determines the active profiles as one of the first steps,
when building the application context.
The active profiles are then used to decide which property files are read and which beans are instantiated.
Once the application is started this cannot be changed.

Comment: I like this answer, but what if you want the profile name to come from the environment? I've tried -Dspring.active.profiles=$SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILES, and setting the OS env var in /etc/profile.d/myenvvars.sh, but Spring Boot doesn't pick that up

Comment: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE works because of the relaxed binding feature of spring boot http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding

Comment: thanks for this answer Stefan, it worked for me, but with one change - the property is actually spring.profiles.active and not spring.active.profiles

Comment: is there any way to pass active profile option for web app at run time ? Default to production env but should be able to activate dev, staging etc at runtime (e.g. through query parameter)

Comment: Whilst Spring profiles can be very useful, in relation to the OP they aren't suitable. This is due to how source code is stored and sensitivity of the properties information stored with that. The OP context is around Database access. For that situation you don't want prod details in plain text in source. This means if the source is compromised then the database is also compromised. It is better to use env variables or secret tools for this instead such as Vault. I prefer env. I'd also make all environments operate the same way in this regards for consistency. It avoids accidents in the future.

Comment: You can use a Spring Boot profile properties file external to the application JAR.  This environment-specific file, for instance, `application-production.properties`, would be deployed to the production machine in a secure way, and would not typically be in the application source code repository.

Comment: Spring profiles do not solve the problem of having different set of database credentials - you won't store them in plain text anyway. Also spring profiles approach (though being useful before) is less and less relevant in containerized world, you don't want to create different images for different environments

Comment: Putting configuration of your external servers inside the codebase is not a good idea. The codebase should be clean of external server configuration for security. Environment variables are safer because, especially for username and password, in a cloud environment like OKD or OpenShift, they can be stored encrypted using a "secret", so only the administrator can set the appropriate values, not the developer.

Answer (score 51):

Flyway doesn't recognize the direct environment variables into the **application.properties** (Spring-Boot V2.1).
e.g

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOSTNAME}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_DATABASE}
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASS}
```

To solve this issue I did this environment variables, usually I create the file .env:

```
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/place
SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=root
```

And export the variables to my environment:

```
export $(cat .env | xargs)
```

And finally just run the command

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Or run your jar file

```
java -jar target/your-file.jar
```

There another approach here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/run-env-variables.html

Comment: What is env-vars?  How are they used.  Your answer refers to things without a complete description and you do not include any links.  I almost downvoted this, but I see your rep is 21 so you are new and one person found your answer useful, so I let it go, but try to provide more information in future answers, and welcome to SO (Stack Overflow).  I hope you enjoy it as much as I do.

Comment: Thanks @PatS, I added more details, hope it will useful.

Comment: Excellent changes.  Thanks updating your answer.

Comment: Link returns 404

Comment: Where would you put this command? `export $(cat .env | xargs)`

Answer (score 16):

This is in response to a number of comments as my reputation isn't high enough to comment directly.

You can specify the profile at runtime as long as the application context has not yet been loaded.

```
// Previous answers incorrectly used "spring.active.profiles" instead of
// "spring.profiles.active" (as noted in the comments).
// Use AbstractEnvironment.ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME to avoid this mistake.

System.setProperty(AbstractEnvironment.ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME, environment);
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml");
```

Answer (score 14):

[Here](https://itexpertsconsultant.wordpress.com/2017/08/05/how-to-load-profile-specific-properties-files-in-spring-boot/) is a snippet code through a chain of environments properties files are being loaded for different environments.

Properties file under your application resources ( **src/main/resources** ):-

```
 1. application.properties
 2. application-dev.properties
 3. application-uat.properties
 4. application-prod.properties
```

Ideally, **application.properties** contains all common properties which are accessible for all environments and environment related properties only works on specifies environment. therefore the order of loading these properties files will be in such way -

```
 application.properties -> application.{spring.profiles.active}.properties.
```

Code snippet here :-

```
    import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
    import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

    public class PropertiesUtils {

        public static final String SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE = "spring.profiles.active";

        public static void initProperties() {
            String activeProfile = System.getProperty(SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE);
            if (activeProfile == null) {
                activeProfile = "dev";
            }
            PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
                    = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
            Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[]
                    {new ClassPathResource("application.properties"),
                            new ClassPathResource("application-" + activeProfile + ".properties")};
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocations(resources);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't Spring Boot handle this scenario out of the box? See [External Config documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties)

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same issue as the author of the question. For our case answers in this question weren't enough since each of the members of my team had a different local environment and we definitely needed to `.gitignore` the file that had the different db connection string and credentials, so people don't commit the common file by mistake and break others' db connections.

On top of that when we followed the procedure below it was easy to deploy on different environments and as en extra bonus **we didn't need to have any sensitive information in the version control at all**.

Getting the idea from PHP Symfony 3 framework that has a `parameters.yml` (.gitignored) and a `parameters.yml.dist` (which is a sample that creates the first one through `composer install`),

I did the following combining the knowledge from answers below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35534970/986160 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/35535138/986160.

Essentially this gives the freedom to use [inheritance of spring configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48330310/yml-config-files-inheritance-with-spring-boot) and choose active profiles through configuration at the top one plus any extra sensitive credentials as follows:

```
application.yml.dist (sample)
```

---

```
    spring:
      profiles:
        active: local/dev/prod
      datasource:
        username:
        password:
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
```

### application.yml (.gitignore-d on dev server)

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  datasource:
    username: root
    password: verysecretpassword
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/real_db?useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
```

### application.yml (.gitignore-d on local machine)

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  datasource:
    username: root
    password: rootroot
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xampp_db?useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
```

### application-dev.yml (extra environment specific properties not sensitive)

```
spring:
  datasource:
    testWhileIdle: true
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    format-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
      naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect
```

Same can be done with .properties

Answer (score 5):

Using Spring context 5.0 I have successfully achieved loading correct property file based on system environment via the following annotation

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:application-${MYENV:test}.properties")})
```

Here MYENV value is read from system environment and if system environment is not present then default test environment property file will be loaded, if I give a wrong MYENV value - it will fail to start the application.

Note: for each profile, you want to maintain - you will need to make an application-[profile].property file and although I used Spring context 5.0 **& not Spring boot** - I believe this will also work on Spring 4.1

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I write this too late, but I have gotten the similar problem when I have tried to override methods for reading properties.

My problem have been:
1) Read property from env if this property has been set in env
2) Read property from system property if this property have been setted in system property
3) And last, read from application properties.

So, for resolving this problem I go to my bean configuration class

```
@Validated
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = ApplicationConfiguration.PREFIX)
@PropertySource(value = "${application.properties.path}", factory = PropertySourceFactoryCustom.class)
@Data // lombok
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    static final String PREFIX = "application";

    @NotBlank
    private String keysPath;

    @NotBlank
    private String publicKeyName;

    @NotNull
    private Long tokenTimeout;

    private Boolean devMode;

    public void setKeysPath(String keysPath) {
        this.keysPath = StringUtils.cleanPath(keysPath);
    }
}
```

And overwrite factory in @PropertySource. And then I have created my own implementation for reading properties.

```
    public class PropertySourceFactoryCustom implements PropertySourceFactory {

        @Override
        public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource resource) throws IOException {
            return name != null ? new PropertySourceCustom(name, resource) : new PropertySourceCustom(resource);
        }


    }
```

And created PropertySourceCustom

```
public class PropertySourceCustom extends ResourcePropertySource {


    public LifeSourcePropertySource(String name, EncodedResource resource) throws IOException {
        super(name, resource);
    }

    public LifeSourcePropertySource(EncodedResource resource) throws IOException {
        super(resource);
    }

    public LifeSourcePropertySource(String name, Resource resource) throws IOException {
        super(name, resource);
    }

    public LifeSourcePropertySource(Resource resource) throws IOException {
        super(resource);
    }

    public LifeSourcePropertySource(String name, String location, ClassLoader classLoader) throws IOException {
        super(name, location, classLoader);
    }

    public LifeSourcePropertySource(String location, ClassLoader classLoader) throws IOException {
        super(location, classLoader);
    }

    public LifeSourcePropertySource(String name, String location) throws IOException {
        super(name, location);
    }

    public LifeSourcePropertySource(String location) throws IOException {
        super(location);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(String name) {

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(System.getenv(name)))
            return System.getenv(name);

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(System.getProperty(name)))
            return System.getProperty(name);

        return super.getProperty(name);
    }
}
```

So, this has helped me.

Comment: This seems really complex. Are you sure you aren't doing something the hard way, that Spring intended to make easy?

Answer (score 3):

If the properties files are externalized as environment variables following run configuration can be added into IDE:

`--spring.config.additional-location={PATH_OF_EXTERNAL_PROP}`

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a dependency [`spring-dotenv`](https://github.com/paulschwarz/spring-dotenv.git) to your build.gradle or pom.xml.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'me.paulschwarz:spring-dotenv:4.0.0'
}
```

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>me.paulschwarz</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-dotenv</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

- Then simply write the secrets in .env as a key value pair.And use it as below

```yaml
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: ${URL}
      username: ${USERNAME}
      password: ${PASSWORD}
      database: ${DATABASE}
```

> If the version is older then write as

```yaml
    spring:
      data:
          mongodb:
              uri: ${env.URL}
              username: ${env.USERNAME}
              password: ${env.PASSWORD}
              database: ${env.DATABASE}
```

Check out complete usage or project on [GitHub](https://github.com/abhisekmohantychinua/snippetsaver.git)

Comment: In current versions of Spring Boot, no additional dependency is required! This works out of the box.