# Environment Variables in spring-boot application.properties error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, environment-variables

I have been looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531661/using-env-variable-in-spring-boots-application-properties) answer to reference environment variables in spring boot application.properties.

However, when I do this an error is returned saying they cannot resolve `$(MYAPP_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}`

**Application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.username = ${MYAPP_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}
```

**Error**

```
org.dbunit.dataset.DataSetException: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user '${MYAPP_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.initialize(DatabaseDataSet.java:243)
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTableMetaData(DatabaseDataSet.java:281)
    at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractOperation.getOperationMetaData(AbstractOperation.java:80)
    at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractBatchOperation.execute(AbstractBatchOperation.java:144)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.setupOrTeardown(DbUnitRunner.java:194)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:66)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:186)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:265)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user '${MYAPP_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1215)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2255)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:307)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:708)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:642)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:464)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:225)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.initialize(DatabaseDataSet.java:185)
    ... 28 more

org.dbunit.dataset.DataSetException: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user '${MYAPP_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.initialize(DatabaseDataSet.java:243)
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTableMetaData(DatabaseDataSet.java:281)
    at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractOperation.getOperationMetaData(AbstractOperation.java:80)
    at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractBatchOperation.execute(AbstractBatchOperation.java:144)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.setupOrTeardown(DbUnitRunner.java:194)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.afterTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:83)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:313)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user '${MYAPP_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1215)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2255)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:307)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:708)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:642)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:464)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:225)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.initialize(DatabaseDataSet.java:185)
    ... 27 more
```

I have set the environment variable in my .bash_profile. I then `source .bash_profile`.

I get the result when

```
> echo $MYAPP_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME
> root
```

I have also restarted eclipse, just to cover all bases.

Comment: Add the rest of the application properties, your jdbc url, driver, ..

Comment: @AliDehghani, the answer from Rahul running eclipse from command line works. I would prefer not to have to do that though.

Comment: OK..also you can upvote the working answer..

Comment: I'm new to spring so I'm not sure if my thinking is correct, but wouldn't it also be possible (and easier) to export environment variable called spring_datasource_username to have spring read it directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set the variable `MYAPP_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME` in .bash_profile. I think that you are launching eclipse as desktop application. If you are launching eclipse as desktop application, it can not read the variable from `.bash_profile`. To resolve this you can use below:

**You can launch your eclipse from command prompt.**

OR

**Set the environment variable in .profile file.**

Comment: I should mention I am on a Mac. The .profile did not work. but running eclipse from the command line did. Any other ideas about running the app not from the command line and resolving the variables?

Comment: any alternatives to the .profile way you can think of?

Comment: @SJC You can add varible in '~/.MacOSX/environment.plist' and you can launch eclipse from desktop.