# Set Spring Boot application.properties based on Environment Variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application that will run in various environments, and based on the environment it runs in, it will connect to a different database. I have a few `application.properties` files, one for each environment which look like such:

`application-local.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=123456789
```

`application-someserver.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://someserver:5432/myproddb
spring.datasource.username=produser
spring.datasource.password=productionpass
```

etc. etc.

On each of my environments, I have a environment variable called `MYENV` which is set to the type of environment it is, for example `local` or `someserver` (the name of the `application-{env}.properties` files perfectly matches the environment name).

How can I get spring boot to read this environment variable and automatically choose the correct `.properties` file? I don't want to have to do the whole `-Dspring.profiles.active=someserver` because of the way this package is deployed (it will not be running as a jar).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using env variable in Spring Boot's application.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531661/using-env-variable-in-spring-boots-application-properties)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> How can I get spring boot to read this environment variable and
>   automatically choose the correct .properties file?

Tell Spring Boot to select the *Active Profile* from the `MYENV` property or environment variable. One way of doing this is to add the following into your `application.properties`:

```
spring.profiles.active=${MYENV}
```

This way Spring Boot will set `spring.profiles.active` to the value of `MYENV` environment variable.

> I don't to have to do the whole -Dspring.profiles.active=someserver
>   because of the way this package is deployed (it will not be running as
>   a jar)

You can use the corresponding environment variable to that `spring.profiles.active`, if you don't like to pass a system property through `-D` arguments. That corresponding environment variable is `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE`. For example if you set the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` to `local`, the `local` profile will be activated. If you're insisting to use `MYENV` environment variable, the first solution is the way to go.

Comment: Is it possible to have a "default" configuration so that in the env variable does not match any files, a standard is chosen?

Comment: Also, put default and common configurations into `application.properties`. It's always will be used but with a lower precedence with respect to profile specific configurations

Comment: @AliDehghani I set values in my system variable but application.properties is not picking it up. Variable name: user Value: pass. In my app.properties spring.datasource.username= ${user}

Comment: Is this possible in Spring context and not in Spring Boot...also do I need to keep the property in application.properties file and then using the active profile over ride the property? - or its if I dont put ebvironment based properties in application.properties and just in its [profile].properties file

Comment: I want minimal dependencies - as I am coding for AWS Lambda - Thanx

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying that application to some container (tomcat, weblogic, ...) you can specify environment variable. For example lets specify environment variable `application1.spring.profiles.active=someserver` and then in your application.properties set property `spring.profiles.active=${application1.spring.profiles.active}`

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring context 5.0 I have successfully achieved loading correct property file based on system environment via the following annotation

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:application-${MYENV:test}.properties")})
```

Here MYENV value is read from system environment and if system environment is not present then default test environment property file will be loaded, if I give a wrong MYENV value - it will fail to start the application.

Note: for each profile, you want to maintain you need to make an application-[profile].property file and although I used Spring context 5.0 **& not Spring boot** - I believe this will also work on Spring 4.1

This is the best solution I believe for my AWS Lambda - with minimal dependencies