# spring - read environment variables from inside the application.properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I specified Spring properties inside the **application.properties** file. How can i populate those properties from the environment variables?

Here is what I tried, but it doesn't seem to work:

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://#{ systemProperties['DATABASE_HOST']}:5432/dbname
spring.datasource.username = postgres
spring.datasource.password = postgres
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using env variable in Spring Boot's application.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531661/using-env-variable-in-spring-boots-application-properties)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can refer to environment properties in the same way you refer to Spring properties using `${...}` syntax.

In your case:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${DATABASE_HOST}:5432/dbname
```

Comment: I have an environment variable name: user and value: pass. In my application.properties I used datasource.username=${user}. It does not read the value

Comment: Is there any way to set the default value in case environment variable is not set?

Comment: You can put default values to application.yml. env properties overwrite them. They have higher priority

Answer (score 4):

Out of the box, as you know, spring-boot expects its Datasource details to be using a specific set of variable names.  Being spring of course you can rework this if you need by a few methods:

1/ If the need to use variables from the environment comes from deployment to a cloud service such as Cloud Foundry or Horuku, there is spring-boot-starter-cloud-connector which handles allot of the plumbing out of the box.  A good read is the ([Binding to Data Services with Spring Boot in Cloud Foundry](https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/27/binding-to-data-services-with-spring-boot-in-cloud-foundry) article and the [Deploying to the cloud](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/cloud-deployment.html) docs which walks you thru this

2/ Instead of relying on Spring-Boot's own auto-magical wiring mechanism, you can create a custom configuration bean to override how the DataSource information is populated.  A good read explaining the annotations involved can be found here:  [Spring Java Config Documentation - @Bean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html) [Configuration JavaDOC](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html).   Based on your example above, here is what I spat out:

```
@Configuration
public class MyDataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource getDataSource() {

        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://" + System.getenv("DATABASE_HOST") + ":5432/dbname";
        String username = "postgres"; 
        String password = "postgres";
        String driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver";

        /*
         * Create the datasource and return it
         * 
         * You could create the specific DS 
         * implementation (ie: org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource) 
         * or ask Spring's DataSourceBuilder to autoconfigure it for you, 
         * whichever works best in your eyes
        */

        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .url( url )
                .username( username )
                .password( password )
                .driverClassName( driverClassName )
                .build();
    }
}
```

Just remember that in spring, you can always override allot of the default behaviours with a little bit of digging!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to. When Spring Boot initializes its environment, it pulls stuff from both the `application.properties` file and any system-level variables and combines them together. The full list of locations where Spring takes them from is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), specifically points **9)** and **10)**.

Comment: thats nice, but in that case I can't use my own property names (which I have to due to the setup here)

Comment: Just shift them around and assign `DATABASE_HOST` to `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` and so forth