# Spring Boot not loading system env vars into application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have exported some simple db creds on my machine as ENV variables.

```
export MYSQL_USER=root
export MYSQL_PASS=pass
```

I'm trying to load these dynamically into my profile into spring boot, but to no avail. I'm starting to believe this is because the application runs inside a TomCat container and therefore isolated from the machine env vars.

## Development Environment Application Properties File

```
spring.datasource.username = ${MYSQL_USER}
```

However, it's still being seen as literal plain text of `${MYSQL_USER}`. Does Spring Boot have the capability for readingg in system environment variables?

Comment: Could you provide a sample project? Are you sure those values are being loaded properly by the profile/user that your SpringBoot app is running under? For example, did you add those exports to a "/etc/profile.d/mysql.sh" file?

Comment: I simply exported these in terminal as shown above, but I have no idea how to actually load system environment variables into Spring Boot.

Comment: Ok, so if you open another terminal and echo those variables without manually exporting them, what get's shown?

Comment: The user name is getting shown in a new terminal instance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring - read environment variables from inside the application.properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703453/spring-read-environment-variables-from-inside-the-application-properties-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also having same problem to get OS env variables into my application.properties/yml using the $ sign. To solve this, I defined the variables to application server(tomcat/jboss etc). Then only the application.properties/yml can get them.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Can you explain how you did this?

Comment: Many ways to do that depending on application server. As you are using tomcat then you can follow as below:
Under Tomcat 's /bin/ create one file - setenv.sh-  (touch setenv.sh) then open (sudo nano setenv.sh) and write


#!/bin/sh

export JAVA_OPTS="-DMYSQL_USER=myuser"

Comment: Make sure to restart tomcat :)