# How to set system environment variables in applicaton.properties the 12 factor way?

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables, properties-file

I am having trouble getting values from my environment variables.. There are many simliar questions. But **NONE** of them worked for me

**Application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
```

**System variables**

```
Variable name : SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
Variable Value : dbuser

Variable name : SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
Variable Value : 123456789
```

**ERROR**

```
invalid username/password; logon denied
```

but when I hard code it, it works fine.

**Update**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using env variable in Spring Boot's application.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531661/using-env-variable-in-spring-boots-application-properties)

Comment: isn't this redundant? spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After defining values in system.environment variables. You must restart eclipse so it can take action, Otherwise it will not read the recently set values.

Comment: had the same issue with IntelliJ. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If you have set your environmvent variables correctly that should work.
For example: `export SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root`

You can also set the properties `spring.datasource.username` and `spring.datasource.password` via the environment variables `SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME` and `SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD`.
Then you don't have to write anything about that into your `application.properties`.

See also the Spring-Boot Documentation about externalized configuration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: I did what you said and removed the user name and password from application.properties. And only have it defined in the environment. I receive the same error.

Comment: How did you set the environment variables? When i'm setting them like this it works: `export SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root`

Comment: why you have "export"? I went to my windows typed environment varibles. and manually added it.

Comment: Ah i see you are using windows. How do you start the application? I think the problem is that your environment variable is not set probably.

Comment: mvn spring-boot:run. I guess my application properties is not reading the environment variables that I set.

Comment: @Jesse, I think David used Linux OS - thus: export SPRING...

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I had to restart not only the IntelliJ IDEA but also my computer in order to make it work.
The environment variables for the data source should be named:

```
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
```

If you name them this way, you don't even have to declare the `spring.datasource.url`, `spring.datasource.username` and `spring.datasource.password` properties anymore, since Spring will auto-detect those environment variables and will create the `DataSource` with the data extracted from them.