# Integrated deployment with profile management for set of Spring Boot microservices with maven

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have 7-8 microservices, in future this number can grow to 25-30. All these services are Spring boot REST services.

What is the best practice to have integrated build for all?

Also, for deployment purpose I have to switch between test and dev profile. How can I make it centralized instead of doing it for each service?

Comment: What is the reason to build all microservices together? Each microservice should be independent (this also applies to build/deployment).

Comment: Just wanted to simplify build process. Currently if i have to switch dev/test profile i have to do it separately for each service. Instead it can be handled at some common config service. I found few references which suggest to have one parent pom project under which all microservice will recide. But not sure if we can change parent for spring boot services.

Answer (score 0):

As microservices should be independent they should not be build or deployed together. Switching between test and dev profile could be performed by checking where the service is deployed with use of environment variables. More information e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531661/using-env-variable-in-spring-boots-application-properties).