# Spring Boot tests always running schema-${platform}.sql

Tags: java, testing, spring-boot, integration-testing

When I run tests on Spring Boot the both `schema-${platform}.sql` and `data-${platform}.sql` is running.

In my scenario I have to remove the schema.sql from tests and set the datasource property `datasource.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`. When I remove the *'Schema 2'* from test folder the *'Schema 1'* keep running.

I have the following directory structure:

```
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   └───resources
│   │       ├───locale
│   │       └───static
│   │       └data-mysql.sql
│   │       └schema-mysql.sql //Schema 1
│   └───test
│       └───resources
│          └data-mysql.sql
│          └schema-mysql.sql //Schema 2
```

-> Both *Schema 1* and *Schema 2* has the same sql instructions.

Is there anyway to keep the `data-mysql.sql` on tests folder, remove the `schema-mysql.sql` from test folder and the tests not run the '*Schema 1*'?

Comment: Related Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531661/using-env-variable-in-spring-boots-application-properties

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to user a different profile for testing

1.
So for testing you would set a system property on the JVM  command line. Such as 
-Dspring.profiles.active=testing -Dspring.profiles.active=ci
or something as random as
-Dspring.profiles.active=raining

2.
You would then create a second  application.properties file  matching the profile

For example 
application-testing.properties

In that properties file you can then specify the location and name 
of the have data file using

spring.datasource.schema=

Spring Boot Profile Documentation
 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Example
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-profiles-example/