# application-test.properties can't access environment variables

Tags: windows, spring-boot, intellij-idea, environment-variables

I have already set environment variables on windows, and actually when I echo them =, I can see their details, however, when I ran tests they seem not to see the environment variables. I have seen similar questions but they weren't helpful. Like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35625508/environment-variables-in-spring-boot-application-properties-error), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45216494/springboot-not-replacing-environment-variables-in-application-properties-file) etc but no luck.

this my `application-test.properties` file

```
## PostgreSQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/users_regsitration_test
spring.datasource.username= ${DB_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password= ${DB_PASSWORD}
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

then, this is the exception am getting :

```
users_regsitration_test
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:108)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:336)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:109)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:108)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:157)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:319)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running it within IDE, then you need to set those variables in "Run Configuration".

I am assuming that you are using either IntelliJ or eclipse, this can be configured as,

1. Eclipse:
   Go to your run configuration as,
   Run -> Run Configuration -> Environment Tab -> Select, this will give you the option to select existing environment variables whichever you want to use for this application.

[image]

2. Same way it can be added to IntelliJ,
   Run -> Edit Configuration -> Environment Variables:

[image]