# Yml config files "Inheritance" with Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-profiles

I couldn't find a straight answer online.

Do Spring Boot's yml files "inherit" from each other? I mean if I have:
`application.yml` which has

```
server:
  port: 80
  host: foo
```

and `application-profile1.yml` which has only

```
server:
  port: 90
```

So if I start my Spring Boot with `profile1` as active profile, will I also have `server.host` property set to `foo`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, `application.yml` file has higher precedence over any `application-{profile}.yml` file. Properties from profile specific yml file will override values from the default `application.yml` file and properties that do not exist in profile specific yml file will be loaded from the default one. It applies to `.properties` files as well as to `bootstrap.yml` or `bootstrap.properties`.

Spring Boot documentation mentions it in [**72.7 Change configuration depending on the environment**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment) paragraph:

> In this example the default port is 9000, but if the Spring profile ‘development’ is active then the port is 9001, and if ‘production’ is active then it is 0.
>
> The YAML documents are merged in the order they are encountered (so later values override earlier ones).
>
> To do the same thing with properties files you can use `application-${profile}.properties` to specify profile-specific values.

Comment: So its probably not possible to create BaseProfile, DerivedProfile1, DerivedProfile2 while both the derived profiles inherit from the base one right?

Comment: Correct. Profile specific `application-{profile}.properties` file inherits from base `application.properties` file and there is no way to do multi level inheritence in this case. Mostly because in this case order of the inheritance  wouldn't be straightforward.

Comment: @tomer.z Actually I was interested in same question and I found a solution for both property files as well as for yaml files - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60380960/384674

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution.

Assume `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  profiles: default-server-config

server:
  port: 9801
  servlet:
    context-path: '/ctp'
```

If I want use `default-server-config` profile, and use port `8080` in my `application-dev.yml`

`application-dev.yml`:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include:
      - default-server-config
      - dev-config

---
spring:
  profiles: dev-config
  
server:
  port: 8080
```

Then `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`

Comment: Unfortunately, 'spring.profiles' configuration property is deprecated

Comment: It's still a good solution with the new format:
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile:
        - default-server-config
        - dev-config
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: 
        - dev-config