# Spring Profile Use For Same Bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles, spring-properties

Hi I am little bit confusign about using profiles in spring.My Scenario is I have a custom properties file.And It is values changes for each environment(dev,test,prod).I use same bean for each environment.But I want to change values for each environments.
In this property files all keys are same,only their values different.

```
mydev.properties 
mytest.properties
myprod.properties
```

So How should I implement profile logic to my code in my scenario(Bean is same ,values are different)

```
//Here is my bean
@Component
@PropertySource("my.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
public class MyProperties
{
....
```

I will add to 'spring.profiles.active' to my propertysource and is this enough?

```
//I plan to add spring.profiles.active

 @Component
 @PropertySource("my${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
public class MyProperties
{
....
```

Comment: Do you need a separate property file or not? If so, look at - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60380960/384674

Comment: Spring will automatically load the properties file corresponding to the active profile if you name them application-<profile>.properties

Comment: Yes,I need separete property file.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the Spring Boot Reference : Section [2.4. Profile-specific Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties)

> In addition to application.properties files, profile-specific
>   properties can also be defined by using the following naming
>   convention: application-{profile}.properties.

One need to define the profile specific properties in `application-{profile}.properties`
and declare the active [profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-profiles)

> You can use a `spring.profiles.active` `Environment` property to specify
>   which profiles are active.

To answer your concern , the property value for the current active profile will be wired to the bean. Also note that

> Profile-specific properties are loaded from the same locations as
>   standard application.properties, with profile-specific files always
>   overriding the non-specific ones, whether or not the profile-specific
>   files are inside or outside your packaged jar.
>
> If several profiles are specified, a last-wins strategy applies. For
>   example, profiles specified by the spring.profiles.active property are
>   added after those configured through the SpringApplication API and
>   therefore take precedence.

In your case , the ideal way to define profile specific properties would be

application-dev.properties

application-test.properties

application-prod.properties