# JPA @TestPropertySource properties doesn't works well

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

`BasePostRepositoryTest`

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@DataJpaTest 
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties") 
public class BasePostRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private BasePostRepository basePostRepository;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;
```

---

`application.yml`

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/knusearch?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=Asia/Seoul&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    username: guestsearch
    password: 

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update 
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        #        show_sql: true
        format_sql: true

  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
```

---

`application-test.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.sql.init.mode=always

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

---

`BasePostRepository`

```
@Repository
public interface BasePostRepository extends JpaRepository<BasePost, Long> {
```

---

I want to test BasePostRepository with In-Memory DB. But an error occured.
Real production environment works with MySQL and is set by `application.yml` .
I add `application-test.properties` and @TestPropertySource but it doesn't works well.

I tested various situations.

- If I set up H2 in `application.yml`  and H2 in `application-test.properties`, it works well.
- If I set up H2 in `application.yml`  and H2(MODE=MySQL) in `application-test.properties`, it works well.
- If I set up MySQL in `application.yml`  and  H2(MODE=MySQL) in `application-test.properties`, it works well.

But,

- If I set up MySQL in `application.yml`  and  H2 in `application-test.properties`, it doesn't work.

Below is the details.

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    create table base_post (
        date_time date,
        encrypted_site_name bit not null,
        post_id bigint not null auto_increment,
        image varchar(8000),
        classification varchar(255),
        encrypted_menu_board_sequence varchar(255),
        encrypted_menu_sequence varchar(255),
        site_name varchar(255),
        title varchar(255),
        url varchar(255),
        image_text text,
        text text,
        primary key (post_id)
    ) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC [Syntax error in SQL statement "\000d\000a    create table base_post (\000d\000a
```

I'm guessing that 'application.yml' also affects `application-test.properties` in any part despite using @TestPropertySource.
Because when I printed AutoWired `DataSource` and `ApplicationContext`'s metatdatas, they were the same as the information of `application-test.properties`.
I couldn't find where the unintended effects were occurring.

Are there some solutions to set hibernate to SQL language of h2?
I think I set it up in `application-test.properties`, but I don't know why it doesn't work.

*I'm sorry I'm not good at English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use, while I was trying to replicate same application with you, you already handled it :)

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.  you so kind 
I have an additional question.
I learned that if I set `spring.jpa.database-platform` property in `application.yml`, `jpa.hibernate.dialect` is set to the same value automatically. 
Is this function only for `application.yml`?
Doesn't it apply to other configuration files such as'`application-test.properties`?

I tried to find the solution in official documentation, but I couldn't. 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-data-access.html

Comment: pleae look at the this answer for this. In your case, If you didn't set spring.jpa.database-platform in test profile, then it will be inherited from application.yml. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48330310/yml-config-files-inheritance-with-spring-boot#:~:text=yml%20file%20has%20higher%20precedence,loaded%20from%20the%20default%20one.

Comment: Thank you so much! They're very informative. I've solved all my questions.

Answer (score 0):

it was solved by adding `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect`