# Spring boot configuration with environment variables

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application which interacts with DB to provide resource using Spring data Rest. I want to get the configuration from environment variables. Below is my properties file.

```
spring.datasource.url=${mysql.url}
spring.datasource.username=${mysql.user}
spring.datasource.password=${mysql.password}
```

And my environment variables are in the image https://ibb.co/cyxsNc

I even tried with the below config too

```
spring.datasource.url=${MySQL_Url}
spring.datasource.username=${MySQL_User}
spring.datasource.password=${MySQL_Password}
```

But I am not able to connect to the DB and getting the below error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
```

Application folder structure

```
Project
|-- src/main/java
    |-- com.example.app
        |-- DemoApplication.java
|-- src/main/resources
    |-- application.properties
```

Note: The configuration works fine if I set the values like below

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ex_man
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't use a screenshot, as the host could go down. A code excerpt is preferable.

Comment: @Sp Sesha, please post your main configuration class (if any) and project structure. Most likely your application context is not picking up your application.properties file (should be on your classpath).

Comment: Well then your environment variables are not loaded with your application. How do you load them into the project?

Comment: where you able to solve your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using env variable in Spring Boot's application.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531661/using-env-variable-in-spring-boots-application-properties)

Answer (score 18):

Check out this documentation here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

try naming your environment variables:

SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL

SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME

SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD

UPDATE:

Spring boot does properly pick up the environment variables, see test below.

```
package com.example.environment_vars;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.util.Map;      // Import this for systemEnvironment

@SpringBootApplication
public class EnvironmentVarsApplication {

    @Value("#{systemEnvironment['ENV_VAR'] ?: 'Default_value'}")
    private String envVar;
    
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {
        return new CommandLineRunner() {
            @Override
            public void run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(envVar);
            }
        };
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EnvironmentVarsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This will print out the value of the environment variable *ENV_VAR* and if the value is not present, it will print the *Default_Value*.

`@Value` injects the value accessible throughout the project.

Comment: Do I need to have a default value specified in the properties file or the environmental variables is enough?

Comment: According to the docs the environment variable should be enough, I haven't tested this out though. Give it a quick test and if it doesn't work we can try another method.

Comment: If I try without a default value in properties file, I am getting an error saying the application failed to start and the description is `Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE`

Comment: Did you make sure to export the environment variables? In the update above I tested and confirmed that the environment variables are picked up by spring boot. Are you running in tomcat or another web server? That may affect access to the environment variables.

Comment: I am confirming that application.properties entries are working for me : spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}

Comment: and I just tested with application.yml     spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
    username: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
    password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}

Comment: What if I want to use some other environment variable name. Say PROD_DATASOURCE_USERNAME? I tried spring.datasource.username=${PROD_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}  but it is still picking up SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME. I have both SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME and PROD_DATASOURCE_USERNAME as environment vars

Comment: @chintanPandya you don't need to put that in your application.yml , Spring automatically picks the env vars and use them instead of reading the file. So you can remove all of that from your file

Comment: Same for @granadaCoder "spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}" is redundant. You can remove that

Comment: Where is it specified in the doc how ENV variables are converted to spring properties?

Comment: @AleksandrErokhin You can find the conversion documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding-from-environment-variables

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [DataSource](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/datasource-configuration/) configuration file and obtain environment variables using [System.getEnv("ENV_VARIABLE")](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_getenv_string.htm) method.

First you should remove properties starting with "spring.datasource." in application.properties. Then include this ready to go configuration file:

```
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
class JpaConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .driverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
                .url(getDataSourceUrl())
                .username(System.getenv("DB_USERNAME"))
                .password(System.getenv("DB_PASSWORD"))
                .build();
    }

    private String getDataSourceUrl() {
        return "jdbc:mysql://"
                + System.getenv("DB_HOST") + "/"
                + System.getenv("DB_NAME")
                + "?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false";
    }
}
```