# Hikari throws an error Property url does not exist on target class org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, kubernetes, hikaricp

I am facing this error from kubernetes cluster. Though it works perfectly from my local server. Here is my application.yml of SpringBoot App

## spring:

```
datasource:
    dataSourceClassName: org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${POSTGRES_HOST}:5432/test_db
    databaseName: test_db
    poolName: SpringBootHikariCP
    username: ${POSTGRES_USER}
    password: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    testWhileIdle: true
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
    openInView: false
    show_sql: true
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate:
        ddl-auto: update
        naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
        use-new-id-generator-mappings: true
    properties:
        hibernate.cache.use_second_levelt_cache: false
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
        hibernate.generate_statistics: true
        hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: validate
```

Here is my Hikari configuration.

```java
            HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
            config.setDataSourceClassName(dataSourceClassName);
            config.addDataSourceProperty("url", url);
            config.addDataSourceProperty("user", user);
            config.addDataSourceProperty("password", password);

            return new HikariDataSource(config);
```

I have checked DB connectivity of kubernetes without Hikari and it works perfectly. So there is no issue with connectivity.
Please help me regarding the issue. I am stuck with this for couple of days.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`${POSTGRES_HOST}` is expecting a [system environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531661/using-env-variable-in-spring-boots-application-properties) that you probably missing in the specific machine, add it for example:

```
export POSTGRES_HOST="1.1.1.1"
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no issue regarding environment variable. I can see application can fetch information from environment variable. for example url is generating like `jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres` . Don't know what's happening when I configure connection to hikaricp into kubernetes.
Thank you

Comment: @shawon did you check connectivity to the host/IP?

Comment: Yes I can connect to the host.

Comment: @shawon can you change to using IP?

Comment: Dear @user7294900 this server is in kubernetes cluster. It usually works with IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `url` to `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_db` or

```
jdbc:postgresql://<host ip>:5432/test_db
```

It looks like the problem with the placeholder `${POSTGRES_HOST}`

Try with localhost

```
datasource:
    dataSourceClassName: org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_db;
    databaseName: test_db
    poolName: SpringBootHikariCP
    username: ${POSTGRES_USER}
    password: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    testWhileIdle: true
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
```

Might be you have not set the environment variable ${POSTGRES_HOST}, that also can be a reason.