# Overriding an application.properties variable from System Variables

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following properties inside config.properties file.

```
resources=/home/pc/work/resources
file1=${resources}/file1
file2=${resources}/file2
file3=${resources}/file3
```

And loading the java.util.Properties to read those properties:

```
properties = new Properties();

    InputStream inputStream = PropertyReader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
    try {
        properties.load(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Apparently, this will always read the values directly from the file.
Is it possible to override the `resources` variable as a system variable while maintaining a default value?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531661/using-env-variable-in-spring-boots-application-properties

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using env variable in Spring Boot's application.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531661/using-env-variable-in-spring-boots-application-properties)