# How can I toggle URL between environments?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-cloud

I've been looking for a way to change the url my microservice is depending on from one environment to another, they told me that I should use spring cloud, and there is currently an application.yml that is used for deployment in openshift, but my knowledge of Spring Cloud is limited and I don't know how to inject the value of the application.yml URL into my java program.

`String uri = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/route";`

I am looking to change this variable depending on whether it is local, or in development

Why? For communication between microservices

```
private RestTemplate call = new RestTemplate();
Arrays.asList(call.getForObject(uri, Object[].class));
```

In local need: `"http://127.0.0.1:8080/route";`

In dev need : `"http://www.myurl.com/route"`

I hope I explained myself well

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Openshift for Java Deployment? If so, please refer to this: https://docs.openshift.com/dedicated/3/dev_guide/environment_variables.html

Comment: Yes, it is not my choice, and for deployments I need a Config file to work in Openshift

Comment: @Bryan mmm i need a enviroment for java, not for Pods, that configuration is done.

Comment: Are you familiar with environment variable? That's how you can change settings between local, dev, prod. You can also look at spring profile  (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)

Comment: @KendeGuzman Yes, but i dont know how can automate my microservice for use dev profile or local profile, i saw can change profile with a maven command, but i dont know if is the best solution. I see this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531661/using-env-variable-in-spring-boots-application-properties), i think is a one solution

Comment: Use Spring profiles. When running local use the local profile in your environment use another. Just specify the profile when starting the service using `--spring.profiles.active=prod` and make sure that there is an `application-prod.properties`. Please don't confuse maven profiles and spring profiles, those are different things!.

Comment: Other option is if you are using maven. You can use maven filters in order to build the artifact for the environment you need

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, i think have the solution for my problem.
As I am using Openshift for deployments, and the local configuration for something else, I have used Spring Cloud with a configuration server, making it use one configuration locally, and in development another one overwriting the local configuration.

This solved my problem, thanks to other guys to answer with any solutions.

Answer (score -2):

As "M. Deinum" and "Ken de Guzman" have already mentioned, use the "Spring Profiles" approach.

See here the docs, which explain the functionality:

- External configuration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config
- Usage of Profiles: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-profiles or https://springframework.guru/spring-profiles/
- In-depth read: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-environment