# Java Spring application.propperties environment variables or default

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I'm trying to make a complete development to the production pipeline.

In this scenario, I want to have a Jenkins job deploy the Java Spring application once a new commit is done.

An example of some of my applications.propperties is:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/application-api?serverTimezone=CET
spring.datasource.username=USERNAME
spring.datasource.password=PASSWORD
```

Once you have this in a git repository your credentials are stored and visual for everyone. I don't have the plan to make anything public yet but seems like a bad idea to store application.properties with passwords on a git repository.

So best case scenario I want something like this, where I can set environment vars on my deployment server:
`spring.datasource.username=${DB_PASS}:PASSWORD` In case of environment variable `DB_PASS` doesn't exist

I'm stuck on how to achieve this. I have seen the usage of `@Value` but I'm unaware of how to use that with given application properties.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using env variable in Spring Boot's application.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531661/using-env-variable-in-spring-boots-application-properties)

Answer (score 3):

You can use all properties also as environment variables.

Simply make the name uppercase and replace . by _

```
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/application-api?serverTimezone=CET
SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=USERNAME
SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
```

Please read the documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config

Comment: the link helped me to discover the profile properties usage. but this still keeps the problem to replacing on repo's

Answer (score 0):

Why are you storing the github credentials in application.properties?

Consider connecting Jenkins to github via Webhooks:

[Here is the plugin for Jenkins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github/)

[Here is a tutorial on setting up and using Github webhooks with Jenkins](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-a-github-webhook-in-your-jenkins-pipeline)

**EDIT 3/24/2020:**
You can consider having a properties file that is external to the project and add it to the classpath (simply don't commit it) using something like `@PropertySource`. Further, once you build your project, you can place a properties file in the same directory and it will be picked up by default when you start your spring boot application.

Example:

`C:<path to project>/target/project.jar`

`C:<path to project>/target/custom-properties.properties`

then

`custom-properties.properties`

will be loaded on start up.

Comment: im not storing credentials for github, but for example a database, an API key or any other secret. Once i commit the application.properties this will be saved in plain text

Comment: And why do you keep it in application.properties?

Comment: @Simon what is the alternative, other than system/environment variables

Comment: Did you read the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config