# how to fill placeholders in application.yaml using jenkins secrets

Tags: spring-boot, docker, jenkins, jib

I got 3 profiles for my application in application.yaml

1. for dev local
2. for build / test during jenkins build
3. for deployment using docker and ConfigMap using JIB

part one and three working ok, what I need to do is to fill my placeholders during test run in jenkins with secrets.

so i need to fill

```
spring:
    config:
        activate:
            on-profile: pipeline
    datasource:
        url: ${pipeline.datasource.url}
        username: ${pipeline.username}
        password: ${pipeline.password}
```

from secrets ?
which plugins ? how ?

Comment: Did you have a look at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531661/using-env-variable-in-spring-boots-application-properties

Comment: Hey, thx for response. that solution uses clear text ! and open shift. while I am using Jenkins, and I need to use a secret provider

Comment: Have you tried using [Jenkins Credential Manager](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/)

Comment: Yeah, we fixed it using "Credentials Binding Plugin",thx.