# Add files to AWS Elastic Beanstalk Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a web app running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with load balancing/auto scaling. I have added various property files within the EC2 instance via ssh.  If the app gets autoscaled then those files I created will be lost.  Is there a way so if it does get autoscaled, those files will go into the new autoscaled instance?  Hope this makes sense? I did read this here, but still unsure [customizing software on linux servers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands)

Thanks

Comment: Property files and to a lesser extent environment variables isn't the right way to configure your serverless architecture. You could consider AWS Parameter Store. Post your coding framework to get further advise.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a legacy app, so would need code changes if not using these property files.  Code framework is Spring Boot / Java / Javascript.  Property files are used to use different database connections based on if live release or a qa release and a few various other things.

Comment: On AWS the abbreviation EBS stands for Elastic Block Store. Elastic Beanstalk would be "EB".

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

Comment: @SteveGreen You then perhaps could use environmental variables (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531661/using-env-variable-in-spring-boots-application-properties). Minimal changes should be needed to bundle a new application properties file into the app.

Comment: Thanks all for the advice, just looking into AWS Param store atm and environment variables (use this a lot with my AWS Lambda's).

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to save those property files outside the EC2 instance for example in an S3 bucket or to a shared disk; So you could seed these with an ebextension on each new instance ([example](https://github.com/rennokki/laravel-aws-eb/blob/master/.ebextensions/00_copy_env_file.config))

I also have an EB application where is highly undesirable. I made a worker instance for this web application which is not auto scaled but I scale this worker instance vertically (bigger instance size). For this application the property files were used for async tasks like sending notifications/emails; The communication for the web instance and worker instance are done via SQS.