# I keep seeing in spring configuration in application.properties or yml, we have ${something}, what is this and How I can set it up ? Beginner here

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

As the title suggests.

If the hostname cannot be determined by Java, then the IP address is sent to Eureka. Only explict way of setting the hostname is by setting eureka.instance.hostname property. You can set your hostname at the run-time by using an environment variable — for example, eureka.instance.hostname=${HOST_NAME}.

The above paragraph is from the spring cloud documentation page, What does it mean please ? And How do I set it up ? or where does it pull the value from ?

And to add context, I am trying to learn how to set up microservices, it takes my laptop name which has underscore in it, and it determines that as an illegal character.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using env variable in Spring Boot's application.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531661/using-env-variable-in-spring-boots-application-properties)

Comment: Also see this article from Baeldung: [Using Environment Variables in Spring Boot’s Properties Files](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-properties-env-variables)